# MySQL Syntax error while attempt to create database with parameterized query in VB.NET

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I am encountering an error while trying to create a new database:

```
Function CreateDatabase(ByVal Name As String) As Boolean
        Dim Query As New MySqlCommand
        Query.Connection = Connection
```

'MySqlConnection is opened in previous functions and this works well.

```
        Query.CommandText = "CREATE DATABASE @database;"
        Query.Prepare()

        Query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@database", Name)

        Try
            Dim AffectedRows As Integer = Query.ExecuteNonQuery()
            If AffectedRows > 0 Then
                Return True
            Else
                Connection.Close()
                Return False
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            Connection.Close()
            Return False
        End Try

    End Function
```

Error occurs on ExecuteNonQuery call and looks like this:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''nameofdatabase'' at line 1
```

I've been trying to fix it for some time but without any result.
Does anyone knows what's wrong with my code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Pls show us how you pass value to the function in vb.net! My guess is that the db name includes single quotes.

Comment: You cannot use a parameter to represent the database name. They can be used only for values in the INSERT/UPDATE or WHERE statements.

Comment: @Steve I'm a bit new to MySql, so I didn't know it's impossible to use parameteres in this kind of query. But isn't it dangerous to insert a database name into the query by simple "CREATE DATABASE " & Name & ";" ? Isn't it vulnerable to sql injection?

Comment: @Shadow Database name comes from textbox, so the call looks like this: CreateDatabase(TextBox1.text). I didn't type any single quotes into the textbox while debugging.

Comment: (Parameters)  It is not a thing of MySql. It is true for any database system I know of. Yes it is true, it is dangerous. But why do you want to let your user create a database? What is the advantage of letting the user choose a database name? How do you handle it afterward?

Comment: Agree with @Steve. The `CREATE DATABASE..` or even `CREATE TABLE...` (basically any DDL statement) should not be in any application code. These are structural schema objects built in in planning stage that should exist long before any scripting.

Comment: @Steve `You cannot use a parameter to represent the database name. They can be used only for values in the INSERT/UPDATE or WHERE statements.`, I disagree somewhat, after MySql 5.0.13 dynamic sql can be ran... Its possible, but should you, ***no***.

Comment: @Codexer you can prepare DDL but you still can't use parameters for object identifiers.  Object identifiers are not strings, not string literals, and not string variables.

Comment: @Steve (and Parfait - cannot notify both of you in one comment) thank you for your answers. Generally, I am programming a system in which every new user is assigned an exclusive database. It's impossible to predict how much of them will be needed in future. Is there any way to avoid creating databases at runtime? Instead of doing this from my code I also thought about using stored procedures or events to perform this actions at server-side. Maybe this is a more secure way?

Comment: @Parfait - just to notify you about my comment above.

Comment: *Every new user is assigned an exclusive database* is not well-designed as it can be runaway application since there is an open-ended user base that can bloat your RDBMS with inefficient storage and maintenance challenges. Simply use **one** database, stack all same structured tables into one and assign user IDs per records. Even set privileges accordingly.

Comment: Thank you @Parfait, it sounds good to me. But let me ask one more question. Supposing I created one database and one table, how would I prevent users to access other users rows in this table? As far as I know I can grant privileges to users on specified columns, but not on specified rows.

Comment: In your application, just query rows by user ID. In any data view/output, do not allow users to see or handle entire data but filtered to only their records. Just like here on StackOverflow, I cannot login to other users' accounts only my own each account query filtered from the SO database(s).